# How to install Imagick on Mac OS with XAMPP

Tags: macos, php, xampp, imagemagick, pecl

I'm having some trouble installing Imagick on a Mac. I have XAMPP installed and when I run `sudo pecl install imagick`, I get this error:

```
checking ImageMagick MagickWand API configuration program... configure: error: not found. Please provide a path to MagickWand-config or Wand-config program.
ERROR: `/private/tmp/pear/temp/imagick/configure --with-imagick="/Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/bin"' failed
```

The error above shows up when I input `/Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/bin` after `Please provide the prefix of Imagemagick installation [autodetect]`

Do I need to install some other library before running the Imagick install command?

Comment: Maybe this helps. http://lists.macosforge.org/pipermail/macports-users/2008-March/009448.html If it did help and you got it to work, write the answer yourself and accept it.

Comment: Thanks for the link...so I managed to finally install it but I can't seem to be able to load the library. When I include `extension=imagick.so` and also the path to the `extensions` folder where the new `modules` folder was created, I get a blank page in localhost/index.php. Any thoughts?

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend using [Brew](https://github.com/mxcl/homebrew/) to install imagemagick instead of MacPorts. Much simpler, imo and less error prone. There is information on the Brew wiki on how to clear out macport installed files so that old installs won't interfere.

On the brew github site, they show you how to quickly install brew. Once brew is installed, you can install imagemagick with `brew install imagemagick`. Also, keep in mind, Brew was designed to not need sudo. Hope this helps.